# How to use the float_format option of the pandas DataFrame.to_csv function?

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I know this problem looks trivial, but the option seems completely ignorant of my setting. I use the following code to format float to have 2 precision digits, but the function seems not to take it.

codes:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame(index=['R'], columns=['C'])
x.loc['R','C'] = 1/3
x.to_csv('test.csv', float_format='%.2f')
```

output:

```
,C
R,0.3333333333333333
```

Answer (score 0):

This is weird. I know it is not exactly the same but you could consider rounding directly the float:

```py
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame(index=['R'], columns=['C'])
x.loc['R','C'] = round(1/3, 2)
x.to_csv('test.csv', float_format='%.2f')
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is a good workaround, I posted this question to make sure that this is a bug other than my misunderstanding about the usage of the option.